# How to compare elements in multiple vectors (of different sizes) against each other?

Tags: matlab

I have three vectors in Matlab that are possibly of different sizes. I want to compare the values in each vector against all the other values in the other vectors and only keep values that are 'close' in 2 out of 3 of the vectors. And by 'keep', I mean take the average of the close values.

For example:

```
a = [10+8i, 20];
b = [10+9i, 30, 40+3i, 55];
c = [10, 60, 41+3i];
```

If I set a closeness tolerance such that only values that are within, say, a magnitude of 1.5 of each other are kept, then the following values should be marked as close:

- 10 + 8i and 10 + 9i
- 40 + 3i and 41 + 3i

Then the routine should return a vector of length that contains the average of each of these sets of numbers:

```
finalVec = [10+8.5i,40.5+3i];
```

What is the most efficient way to do this in Matlab? Is there a better way than just straightforward looping over all elements?

Comment: I suggest you first do it with loops and then think about vectorizing, as this is not an obviously straightforward vectorizable option. "early optimization is the root of all evil"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Building on [this solution](https://fr.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/98191-how-can-i-obtain-all-possible-combinations-of-given-vectors-in-matlab):

```
a = [10+8i, 20];
b = [10+9i, 30, 40+3i, 55];
c = [10, 60, 41+3i];

M1 = compare_vectors(a , b);
M2 = compare_vectors(a , c);
M3 = compare_vectors(b , c);
finalVec = [M1, M2 , M3]


function M = compare_vectors(a , b)

    % All combinations of vectors elements
    [A,B] = meshgrid(a,b);
    C = cat(2,A',B');
    D = reshape(C,[],2);

    % Find differences lower than tolerance
    tolerance = 1.5
    below_tolerance = abs(D(:,1) - D(:,2)) < tolerance ;

    % If none, return empty
    if all(below_tolerance== 0)
        M = [];
        return
    end

    % Calculate average of returned values
    M = mean(D(below_tolerance,:));

end
```

Answer (score 2):

```
% your data   
a = [10+8i, 20];
b = [10+9i, 30, 40+3i, 55];
c = [10, 60, 41+3i];
tol = 1.5;

% call the function with each combination of vectors and concatenate the results
finalVec = cell2mat(cellfun(@closepoints, {a, a, b}, {b, c, c}, {tol, tol, tol}, 'Uni', 0))

function p = closepoints(a, b, tol)
    % find the pairs of indexes of close points 
    %    the bsxfun() part calculates the distance between all combinations of elements of the two vectors
    [ii,jj] = find(abs(bsxfun(@minus, a, b.')) < tol);
    % calculate the mean
    p = (a(jj) + b(ii))/2;
end
```

Note that [cellfun()](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html) isn't really faster than calling the function multiple times in a row or using a for loop. But it would be easier to add more vectors than the former and is IMO nicer to look at than the latter.

Comment: Your solution have a similar problem that mine had: finalVec has an empty cell when no comparisons are below tolerance. That is why I added the option to return an empty array.

Comment: Is that really a problem? IIRC you can concatenate empty vectors together with other ones. E.g. doesn't `[[1 2] [] 4]`  result in `[1 2 4]`?

Comment: To me it is not a problem at all, but it does not correspond to op's `finalVec`. Just a minor detail!

Comment: I forgot that cellfun with uni = 0 returns a cell and not a series of vectors. Got it now I think, thx a lot!